# Add class name only, conditonally

Tags: jquery, css

I am using a plugin which determines the brightness of a div's background-color and dynamically applies a "light" or "dark" class to it. I'm trying to grab that class and apply it to another div in order to style it based on the returned value.

```
var topbar = $(".top-bar");
if ($(".quote-block").is( "dark" ) ) {
    topbar.addClass('background--dark');
};
if ($(".quote-block").is( "light" ) ) {
    topbar.addClass('background--light');
};
```

To streamline this however, it would be ideal to return just the class name alone and append it to the "background--" (i.e.: "background--" plus the "dark" class yielded by plugin, resulting in `.background--dark`). How can I achieve this with JQ? Clearly I am a novice so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

This is the intended structure:

```
<nav class="top-bar"></nav>
<div class="main-content">
    <section class="quote-block light<--dynamic class"></section>
    <section class="quote-block dark<--dynamic class"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use the plugin on both divs?

Comment: Thanks. I am using the plugin on all ".quote-block" divs. Depending on the brightness of the background color of the div the plugin adds either a "light" or "dark" class to it.

Comment: So are the `.quote-block` elements actually `<light>` or `<dark>`?

Comment: Can you please post corresponding `HTML`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making this up because there was no HTML supplied in your question. Hopefully this can still help you.

```js
function getLight() {
  var prefix = "background--";
  
  return $(".quote-block").hasClass("dark") ? (prefix + "dark") : 
         $(".quote-block").hasClass("light") ? (prefix + "light") : "";          
}

$(".top-bar").addClass(getLight());
```

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
}

.background--dark {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-bar"></div>
<div class="quote-block dark"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy. The top-bar element is the nav of the site, it's not within the quote-block div. Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I've included the HTML

Comment: Works. Thanks so much!